# UIPopover without any arrows

Tags: uikit, ipad, uipopovercontroller

Is it possible to present a popover without any sort of arrows pointing somewhere?

Comment: So you want a modal view controller?

Comment: Are you're suggesting that I use `-presentModalViewController:animated:`? That's extremely different from a UIPopover. It doesn't provide the same look and feel as a UIPopover, and you're limited to certain fixed dimensions.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Yes it is possible just do:

```
 [self.popoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:anItem   
                                permittedArrowDirections:0
                                                animated:YES];
```

The zero represent no direction.

Comment: it works for me!!! thanks.. will apple accept this? ... by the way, is it posible to present a keyboard inside a popover, the way it looks on ipad passcode? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3636560/how-to-present-keyboard-inside-popover-ipad-passcode-lock-style

Comment: Setting this parameter to 0 breaks the sizing of my popover.

Comment: Try creating subclass of UIPopoverBackground class and override arrowDirection getter method. In that method return 0.

Comment: For swift use UIPopoverArrowDirection.allZeros

Comment: this is not working for iOS 9. there is no allZeros property. Xcode did autocorrect that to just using (). so UIPopoverArrowDirection() works on iOS 9

Answer (score 26):

For iPhone and swift 2.0 try this one

Code to initiate popover

```
initiatePopover(){
    let popoverContent = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("XYZController") as! XYZController
    let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: popoverContent)
    nav.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover
    let popover = nav.popoverPresentationController
    popoverContent.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(250 ,200)
    popover!.delegate = self
    popover!.sourceView = self.view
    popover!.sourceRect = CGRectMake(200,200,0,0)
    popover!.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection(rawValue: 0)
    self.presentViewController(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

And add this to your ViewController

```
func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    return UIModalPresentationStyle.None
}
```

Answer (score 20):

**Swift4**:

```
popover.permittedArrowDirections = []
```

Answer (score 11):

Set the `permittedArrowDirections` to 0.

```
permittedArrowDirections:0
```

Code -

```
[self.popoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:anItem   
                                permittedArrowDirections:0
                                                animated:YES];
```

Zero tells "NoDirection".

Comment: You can also do it in the storyboard segue by deselecting all the arrow direction checkboxes.

Answer (score 9):

**Swift3**, this code work for me

```
popover.permittedArrowDirections = .init(rawValue: 0)
```

Answer (score 5):

For **`Swift 2.0` and `iOS9`** the solution is:

```
popoverViewController?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection()
```

Comment: Value of type 'UIPopoverController' has no member 'permittedArrowDirections'

Comment: @SpyZip This works. Maybe you forgot the question mark.

Answer (score 5):

In swift 3, you can build a `UIPopoverArrowDirection` extension for this:

```
extension UIPopoverArrowDirection {
    public static var noArrow: UIPopoverArrowDirection {
        return UIPopoverArrowDirection(rawValue: 0)
    }
}
```

and the you can do:

```
popoverPresentationController!.permittedArrowDirections = .noArrow
```

Answer (score 5):

In Swift, you can simply do:

```
popoverPresentationController.permittedArrowDirections = []
```

Since in another configuration you could have used:

```
popoverPresentationController.permittedArrowDirections = [.up, .down]
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this , it works for me.

```
[self.popoverViewController presentPopoverFromRect:rect inView:self.view  permittedArrowDirections:0 animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case for swift developers

```swift
popoverController.sourceView = self.view
popoverController.sourceRect = self.view.bounds
popoverController.backgroundColor = UIColor.brownColor()

popoverController.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.init(rawValue: 0)
popoverController.sourceRect = CGRectMake(width/4, hieght/4, width/2, hieght/2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Nope, there is no `UIPopoverArrowDirectionNone` option, and `UIPopoverArrowDirectionUnknown` throws an exception i think if you try to use that to present.

Instead of a popover controller, you can call `presentModalViewController:animated:` and set the controller you are presenting to have a modal presentation style of `UIModalPresentationFormSheet` or perhaps `UIModalPresentationPageSheet`.  Those are more traditional popup screens than popovers are.

Comment: Unfortunately, presentModalViewController is limited to certain particular frame sizes, while popovers are not, unless I'm missing something. They also don't provide the same look and feel as a popover.

Comment: That's correct.  Unfortunately, if your requirements are strict you may have to roll your own popups to get what you want.

Answer (score 2):

This works fine for me.

```
[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)
                                    inView:self.view 
                  permittedArrowDirections:NULL 
                                  animated:YES];
```

Enjoy Coding.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use Popovers if you don't want to show arrows. Present your view controller as a Modal and use a UIModalPresentationFormSheet instead.

Example:

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MyStoryBoard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController* viewController = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myViewController"];
viewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[presenterViewController presentViewController: viewController animated:YES completion:^{

}];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
[popOverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 40) inView:popOverContentView permittedArrowDirections:0 animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 1):

I use popover to show menu depending on touch coordinate.
In this case popover uses maximum height of self.view

```
CGRect popeverFrame = CGRectMake(touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y, 0, 0);
[self.popover presentPopoverFromRect:popeverFrame
                              inView:self.view
            permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                            animated:YES];
```

But when I use 0-direction. Popover rectangle doesn't set it height to maximum and can only be set by appropriate property.

```
CGRect popeverFrame = CGRectMake(touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y, 0, 0);
[self.popover presentPopoverFromRect:popeverFrame
                              inView:self.view
            permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                            animated:YES];
```

Hope this will help: [Help with UIPopOverController size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770987/help-with-uipopovercontroller-size)

Answer (score 0):

To make a pop over direction none and make it to appear in center of the view controller :

```
let PopSrnVar = popoverPresentationController
let ConRctVar = view.frame
PopSrnVar!.sourceRect = CGRectMake(ConRctVar.width/4, ConRctVar.height/4, ConRctVar.width/2, ConRctVar.height/2)
// To make arrows as none
PopSrnVar!.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection()
```

Answer (score -3):

A simple solution in SWIFT:

```
popover!.permittedArrowDirections = nil
```