# UIPopover locking background view

Tags: ipad, uipopovercontroller

I am trying to replicate the iPad passcode view.  Which basically is a popover with no arrow direction, that locks the background view kinda like a modal view controller.

My question: Is there a way to lock the underlying background view when presenting a popover.

My idea:  The only real solution that i could come up with is placing that popover inside a modal view controller.  and presenting it that way.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `modalInPopover` property of your view controller: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW72

This question provides some information on making a popover with no arrows, though it's not clear whether it's correct or not: [UIPopover without any arrows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400852/uipopover-without-any-arrows)

Comment: Perfect! lol an by the way i posted the correct answer on how to display a popover without arrows ;)  But thanks for the answer