# iOS Popover UI Element

Tags: ios, ipad

I am planning to create UI Popver element with a text entry and buttons similar to 
http://www.ofzenandcomputing.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/enter-password.png

Clicking elsewhere on the screen should not dismiss the popover and only the cancel or save button should dismiss the popover.

Does the iPad password setup screen use UIPopoverController ? How do I enforce the popover from being dismissed ONLY from a cancel button in the pop up ?

Comment: Is that not a view controller presented modally

Answer (score 0):

That is indeed a UIPopover.  On iOS versions prior to 3.2, UIPopover contains a property called passThroughViews.  Pass an NSArray with self.view as the sole object to that method and your popover will not dismiss when the view is tapped.

Comment: [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5477422/is-there-a-way-not-to-have-the-popover-dismissed-when-pressing-outside-it)

Comment: another related question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627926/uipopover-locking-background-view

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can by using popoverView's delegate:

```
-(BOOL)popoverControllerShouldDismiss:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
{
    if ([save or cancel button is tapped]) {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```