# How to present keyboard inside popover?, ipad passcode lock style

Tags: ipad, uipopovercontroller, uikeyboard, popover

Is it posible to present a keyboard the way is shown when you set a passcode for your ipad?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately no, But what i did to replicate this was,  built a bunch of buttons like a keyboard inside my passcode view using interface builder.  Then linked each button to a command that would change the text field.

```
- (IBAction) button9_clicked:(id) sender{

    if ([self textField:theTextField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:range replacementString:@"9"]){
        self.theTextField.text=[self.theTextField.text stringByAppendingString:@"9"];
        range.location = self.theTextField.text.length;
    }
    else 
        range.location = self.theTextField.text.length;
}
```

Comment: jeje yep, I did the same!... UIButtons with background images for normal and Highlighted state. Thank you for the answer