# uipopover hides when keyboard shows

Tags: ios5, uitextfield, uipopovercontroller, cordova

i have an UIpopover with UItextfield in it, when i open popover and tap on uitextfield then keyboard shows, but it hide the popover. How can i show keyboard without hiding UIpopover?
i am calling popover in UIWebView because i use cordova 1.8.1, but i tried it in UIView too, and it hides too.
here code of calling UIpopover :

```
if (popEl==nil){
    popEl=[[Popover alloc] init];
}
if (pcs==nil){
    pcs=[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popEl];
    pcs.delegate=self;
}
[pcs presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1) inView:self.webView permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:NO];
```

P.S. Sorry for my English, i am from Ukraine.

Answer (score 1):

firstly i recommend you to go through the apple documentation of [UIPopOverController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html)

for your problem i think you have to deal with the appearance and disappearance of Keyboard here's the solution to handle this problem [Check it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428425/uipopovercontrollers-view-controller-gets-resized-after-keyboard-disappears/5733411#5733411)

Comment: you didn't understand me, i open popover tap on textfield keyboard shows but popover hides(without calling popoverControllerDidDismissPopover or popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover). i need to left popover on screen when keyboard shows.

Comment: You'd have to implement your own keyboard to do this. [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3636560/how-to-present-keyboard-inside-popover-ipad-passcode-lock-style?rq=1) it resolve your problem

Comment: i have found the problem, i set UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny and it works, previously it was UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp

Comment: The UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp is the solution,brilliant! You save my day SergeyM! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is that, when U click on the textField the pop over view should appear,right? if yes, then add this code before you add the popoverview,

```
[textField resignFirstResponder];
```