# Set UIPopOverController size

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiscrollview, uipopovercontroller, popover

I have a `view` with a bunch of button in a `UIScrollView`.  When the user presses a button, I want a UIPopOverController to display pointing at the selected button.  It kind of works, but the popover is the wrong size and points to a random point in the view.  Here is my code.

```
-(void)detail:(id)sender{
    UIButton *button = sender;
    NSLog(@"tag = %i", button.tag);

    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    self.popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navController];
    self.popover.delegate = self;
    [self.popover presentPopoverFromRect:button.bounds inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
}
```

Than the problem with the size of the popover:
In the view that is inside the popover, I have:

```
self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = scroll.contentSize;
NSLog(@"%f, %f", scroll.contentSize.height, scroll.contentSize.width);
NSLog(@"showing: %f, %f",  self.contentSizeForViewInPopover.height,  self.contentSizeForViewInPopover.width);
```

and both logs are matching.  So I think everything should work correctly.  But it doesn't.  Here is a screen shot.  Let me know if you need more of my code.  Thanks in advance.

[image: screen shot of the error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the size of the popover only: I managed to do it with a variable heighted UILabel:

```
UILabel *hinweis;
hinweis.text = @"...";
hinweis.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,width,800);
[hinweis sizeToFit];
```

And for the arrow: have you tried a different inView param like self.parentViewController.view?

Comment: In the meantime I learned to use contentOffset for a tableView, it should be analog for a scrollView. `        CGRect f = [tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        CGPoint yOffset = [tableView contentOffset];
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(f.origin.x, f.origin.y + 45 - yOffset.y, 200, 40);
        [self.poc presentPopoverFromRect:frame ...`

Comment: Also, you need to initialize that UILabel.

Answer (score 23):

First thing I noticed is that you should be using the button.frame not the button.bounds for the *from* rectangle. The difference between these [UIView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) properties:

> The geometry of a view is defined by its frame, bounds, and center
>   properties. The frame property defines the origin and dimensions of
>   the view in the coordinate system of its superview and is commonly
>   used during layout to adjust the size or position of the view.
>
> The bounds property defines the internal dimensions of the view as it
>   sees them and is used almost exclusively in custom drawing code.

You can set the height of your [popover](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html) controller using its [setPopoverContentSize](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIPopoverController/setPopoverContentSize%3aanimated%3a) message:

```
// so something like this ...
[self.popover setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 460)];
// and to bind the popover to your button 
[self.popover presentPopoverFromRect:button.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Comment: changing `presentPopoverFromRect` to `frame` made it a little better.  But I think part of the point problem is due to the fact that the buttons are in a `UIScrollView`, so the origional button frame is no longer the frame when the popover is presented.  Also, I can't set the popover frame like that because I want to to change depending on the size of the text inside the popover