# Cordova CameraPopover without any arrow

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, camera, cordova-plugins

I need to show an CameraPopover without any arrow. 
What I have tried till now is:

```
var popover = new CameraPopoverOptions(300,300,100,100,0); 
var options = {
                    quality: 75,
                    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                    sourceType: value,
                    allowEdit: false,
                    encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
                    popoverOptions: popover,
                    saveToPhotoAlbum: false
                };
```

In the last parameter of `CameraPopoverOptions(300,300,100,100,0)`, I have tried passing 0, undefined, null and other numbers except (1,2,4,8,15) because these numbers are already defined in Camera cordova plugin

```
Camera.PopoverArrowDirection = {
        ARROW_UP : 1,        // matches iOS UIPopoverArrowDirection constants
        ARROW_DOWN : 2,
        ARROW_LEFT : 4,
        ARROW_RIGHT : 8,
        ARROW_ANY : 15
    };
```

In native there is one [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400852/uipopover-without-any-arrows) but for Cordova project how to do it? Any workaround or suggestion will help.

Answer (score 1):

Well, with the current code base of the [camera plugin project](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera), you can't.

Your `zero` is not recognized because in the `Camera.m` [class implementation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera/blob/master/src/ios/CDVCamera.m) at the `initialize` method, there is a set of allowed values :

```
 org_apache_cordova_validArrowDirections = [[NSSet alloc] 
 initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp], 
 [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown], 
 [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft], 
 [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIPopoverArrowDirectionRight], 
 [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny], nil];
```

Since your `zero` doesn't appear there, it affects the value `UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny` :

```
if (![org_apache_cordova_validArrowDirections containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:arrowDirection]]) {
arrowDirection = UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny;
}
```

If you want, you can fork the the plugin and add the permitted arrow direction `0`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Zakaria.. I have not still got any solution with the current code base but still not accepting ur solution coz I still think there might me any answer. Hence keeping options open. :)